# tcpclient C3145

Tags: dll, global, tcpclient

I'm currently using Visual Studio C++ to generate .dll in order to transmit data between two programs: essentially, one program notifies the other when an event occurs. I'm trying to do this via a TcP client socket.

my header file goes something like this:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec (dllexport) bool trackerConnect( char* ipAddress, int port );
    __declspec (dllexport) void sendEvent ( char* ev);
    __declspec (dllexport) void disconnect();
}
```

My .cpp file looks something like this

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include "logEvents.h"
#using "system.dll"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System::Text;

TcpClient^ logClient;
NetworkStream^ logStream;

bool trackerConnect( char* ipAddress, int port )
{
    /*Connects to server, gets stream, and returns whether the connection was
    successful or not*/
}

void sendEvent ( char* ev )
{
    /*Converts ev into a Byte array and sends it to the server to notify it 
    that an event has occurred*/
}

void disconnect ()
{
    //closes the connection with the server
}
```

Given that all three functions need access to the TcPClient, I declared it as a global variable. However, when I compile, I get error C3145: global or static variable may not have managed type. If I can't declare the TcPClient as a global variable, how am I supposed to use it in the three functions?